# BokehPass inconsistent results

Tags: three.js

BokehPass is giving me some strange results. FilmPass and BloomPass have no effect on the issue. Code:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xc3defc );
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 85, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.set(20,1,20);
camera.rotation.y = .8;
var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x080820, 1 );
scene.add( light );

var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
var bokehPass = new THREE.BokehPass( scene, camera, {
    focus:  100.0,
    aperture:   0.00001,
    maxblur:    1.0,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
} );
bokehPass.renderToScreen = true;

composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );
composer.addPass( new THREE.FilmPass( 0.3, 0, 0, false ) );
composer.addPass( new THREE.BloomPass( .2 ) );
composer.addPass( bokehPass );

renderer.autoClear = false;

console.log(composer);


var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load(
    'main1.obj',
    function ( object ) {

        scene.add( object );
    }
);


var animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                composer.render();
                camera.position.z -= 0.001;
};

animate();
```

Pic:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsZtZ.jpg
Those are not JPG artefacts.

This is with aperture value of 0.1, it gets even crazier:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0TD0.jpg

Any clue what is happening here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it! Changing camera's near clip to 0.01 fixed the issue. Everything in z-buffer was white before that so obviously there is no depth resolution there. Now there is more range in the low-end.